# Which one is the best in Appium and selendroid?

Tags: automated-testing

which one should i  use for functional testing and locking my scenario

Comment: You can search this on Google. And this is too opinion based. One who loves Appium will always support while the other will support Selendriod.

Comment: but i want review from those who already use both.

Comment: So you should change your question to more like what are the differences between X and Y. And you should give some more context, what is your scenario. Also it is unclear what you mean by "locking my scenario".

Comment: What car I should buy? Oh, and I forgot to tell you that it is not for commuting, but I need it to haul concrete. We are building a dam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, it all depends what you want to test.
Here are some insights differences between them:

- Selendroid can be used only on Android while Appium can be used on Android, iOS, and FirefoxOS (not sure if this is out of development as of now though)
- they both support Native, Hybrid and Mobile Web applications
- User agent testing and cross platform is supported only by Appium
- they both support emulators, real devices and cloud testing
- they both support the Selenium Grid
- not sure about Selendroid, but Appium has good documentation and also a vast community including various blogs, tutorials, etc

Now, as I said, it all depends what you have under test, what platforms needs to be supported, what's your experience with one vs the other, etc, etc

Comment: Thx its really helpful for me. I can decide now, what should i use.